# Prove or disprove: $\phi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\text{, }\phi(n) = \lfloor n \cdot | \sin( \sqrt{2} \cdot n ) | \rfloor$ is surjective

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How do I go about proving or disproving that the following function is surjective?
 Is there some sort of standard trick for integer functions?

$$\phi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \\ \phi(n) = \lfloor n \cdot | \sin( \sqrt{2} \cdot n ) | \rfloor$$

where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the function that returns the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Thanks in advance.

(PS: it's not a homework question or anything, I'm just curious)

Comment: I imagine that a proof in the positive direction will make use of the fact that $\sin(n)$ is dense in $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: Replacing $\sin(\sqrt{2} n)$ by $n\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\pi }-\lfloor n\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\pi} \rfloor$ doesn't change the problem a lot. Then you are asking if we can make the Diophantine approximation/[irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) of $\omega_m = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\pi m}$ uniform on $m$.

Comment: @DuncanRamage I thought so as well, I just couldn't figure out how to how to compensate the "growth" of the n multiplier... But it's really just a silly question, if there isn't any obvious way of doing it, I'll just delete the question.

Comment: @mlaci Please don't delete this question, I think it's very interesting, even if it's just silly.

Comment: @reuns Thank you very much. I had never seen any of the concepts on that page, and I'm having a hard time grasping them, but I'll keep trying. Is the answer to the question more or less independent of the choice of $\sqrt{2}$ (instead of any other irrational number)? Edit: nevermind the last part, I obviously hadn't read enough of the wikipedia page.